# How to expand a div to match another div

Tags: html, css

I have a section that I am wanting to expand with an expanding menu I have on the right hand side. Right now my section, `projects-main-section`'s height is set at `800px`. Obviously, this will not expand with the expandable menu on the right. I have tried setting the height to 100% and 100 vh, but both of those methods did not work.

So I have both sections, the `projects-main-section` and `project-section-container` (the expandable menu on the right) wrapped around a main container `projects-main`. I figured this would help to get the `projects-main-section` to grow with it, but no luck so far.

So, as the expandable menu grows in height, I want the `projects-main-section` to grow with the expanding `projects-main` parent div, but not exceed the footer.

How can I do this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0etxp2oj/)

Here is what it looks like static.

[image: Static]

When the menu expands, it looks like this. You will see the left container, `projects-main-section`, has a large gap under it from the footer.

[image: Expanded]

```
<div id="projects-main">
        <div id="projects-main-section">
            <div id="projects-main-section-title-wrap">
            </div>
        </div><div id="project-section-container">
    </div>
</div>

#projects-main {
    height: auto;
}
#projects-main-section, #project-section-container {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#projects-main-section {
    height: 800px;
    background: #6f9697;
    width: 40%;
}
#project-section-container {
    height: auto;
    width: 60%; 
}
```

Comment: `height: 100%` to columns if it's inside `#projects-main` only for this columns.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful here since you say that some things don't work.

Comment: @Paulie_D Here you are: https://jsfiddle.net/0etxp2oj/ ... I just didn't want to bombard the question with code. Click Project 1 to see the issue the best.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude i tried to do `height: 100%` to that container and it only goes to the end of my text.

Comment: Can you use `flexbox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest using `flex`

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
}
.flex{
  display:flex;
}
.flex.column {
  flex-direction: column
}
.over, .under {
  background: #0099cc;
  height: 75px;
}
.content{
  flex: 1;
}
.left_col {
  background: orange;
  width: 50%;
}
.right_col {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex column container">
  <div class="over">
  </div>
  <div class="flex content">
    <div class="left_col">
      Grows with right column
    </div>
    <div class="right_col">
      long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
      long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
      long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
      long content last
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="under">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example is what I am after, but I modified it to fit what I had and it doesn't work the same way. You can see it here: http://optimumwebdesigns.com/eslich/projects

Comment: @Becky Will have a look soon, let you know

Comment: @Becky Add `display: flex;` to your `#projects-main-content` rule

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks s much!